# JSON Data not Being Sent

Tags: ajax, post

I have the following 'stringified' JSON data:

```
$jsonData = '[{"tnum":"1","tnam":"Title1","snum":"24","word1":"this","word2":"is fun"},{"tnum":"343","tnam":"Title2","snum":"233","word1":"hello","word2:"again"}]'
```

My AJAX is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "doSave3.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function() {
        alert("Data saved");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Data were not saved");
    }
});
```

And the PHP on the server side is:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    $jsonData = $_POST['data'];

    $result = json_decode($jsonData);

    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO saved_lists (id, title_number, title_name, sub_number, word1, word2) VALUES (NULL, $value->tnum, '$value->tnam', $value->snum, '$value->word1', '$value->word2')";
            mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested the PHP and it works when I set manually set $jsonData inside doSave3.php. Note that when doing this test, I also have to remove if(isset($_POST['data'] or it won't get past the if statement. When I revert back to relying upon $_POST['data'] there is no action so I am pretty sure doSave3.php is not receiving the POST data.

Some help would be appreciated. I've gone over all the similar posts and corrected a few things, but no dice as yet.

Comment: You should use something like `print_r($_POST)` at the top of your PHP file to see exactly what's being sent in.

Comment: Ok, I've added this, but where do I actually see the log? That's one thing that prevented me from doing a bit of further debug myself, since I don't know how to see this value due to it being an AJAX call.

Comment: It'll be returned in the server response. You can use something like Firebug or the Chrome developer console to view the raw response from your server.

Comment: remove contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' and add data: 'data='+ $jsonData and try print_r($_POST['data'])

Comment: Thanks people, made both of the above changes and it works. Both changes were required to make it work. I would have thought that you'd have to send as datatype json though? Anyway, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh.. the problem is with your json string. you are missing a double quotes at the end of the string `"word2:"again"` this should be `"word":"again"`.

```
var jsonData = '[{"tnum":"1","tnam":"Title1","snum":"24","word1":"this","word2":"is fun"},{"tnum":"343","tnam":"Title2","snum":"233","word1":"hello","word2":"again"}]';
$.ajax({
    url: "echo.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'data='+jsonData,
    success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    },
    error: function() {
    alert("Data were not saved");
    }
});
});
```

and in echo.php

```
$json = urldecode($_POST['data']);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Everything works fine with the double quotes.:)

Comment: Thanks for that, in my testing I was using a slightly different JSON string which did have all the quotes in the correct places. Your earlier comment did solve my problem though.